# Graph API to check in with Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios6, checkin, facebook-checkins

I am using Facebook SDK 3.1.1 for login as well as check in with Facebook.
login with Facebook it's working fine but CheckIn with using graph API give error.

This are all the permission I am giving for checkin 
@"friends_status",@"user_checkins", @"friends_checkins",@"user_status".

and here is the request:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:message 
                                        place:placeId 
                                         tags:nil 
                            completionHandler:
      ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"Response....... \n\n %@  %@ %@",connection,result,error);
      }
];
```

Response:

> )>  (null) Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"
>   UserInfo=0x808a5a0
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={type = mutable dict, count = 2, entries =>    1 : {contents = "code"} = {value = +403, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}     2 : {contents = "body"} = {type = mutable dict, count = 1, entries =>    11 : {contents = "error"} = {type = mutable dict, count = 3, entries =>    2 : {contents = "type"} = {contents = "OAuthException"}  3 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action"}  6 : {contents = "code"} = 200 }
>
> }
>
> } , com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403}

Can anybody help me out what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The `location` parameter of a [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) requires the `read_stream` permission.